# How do I save a query in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

How do I save a query in pgAdmin 4?  No matter where I try to save it within the PostgreSQL file or the pgAdmin 4 file, the result is that I do not have access.

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\

I have tried both bin files, data files, and many other files.

It always says that I don't have access.

I see that I can save data output as a CSV file, but I want the actual query.

If I close pgAdmin, I lose everything in the query.

Comment: Did you find an answer on this one? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 21):

I assuming that query means that you type query in Query tool.

> Default location:
>   C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\storage

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Generally when we click the save button a window is opened(look at fig1).
[We can see that create option is disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXeVf.png)

**What to do?**
Just write the file_name.sql at that address(look at fig2).
[We can see that create option is enabled. Click on create button to save.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0TIx.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have to write the file name in the location. For example: C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\storage\query1.sql

Comment: That has to be the worst save UX I've seen. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04 pgadmin 4 saves files on the following path

```
/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/your_user/files
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the save button you select the folder you want to save the query in, when you choose it,
in the path, literally, after the / enter what you want to name the created file, you will notice that the create button is enabled as you type!